# lightning:fileupload - Reduce number of files to upload to a single file at a time

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, files, upload

As I understand, the *multiple* attribute, when set to false, will limit the number of files uploaded at a time to 1:

> Specifies whether a user can upload more than one file simultanesouly. This value defaults to false.

Reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_fileUpload.htm).

However, even if I explicitly set this value to false, I am still able to select multiple files to upload at a time, either via the document selector window, or the drag-and-drop:

### Code snippet:

```
<lightning:fileUpload 
    label="Attach receipt"
    multiple="false" 
    accept=".pdf, .PDF, .png, .PNG, .jpg, .JPG"
    recordId="{!v.recordId} " 
    onuploadfinished="{! c.handleUploadFinished }" />
```

### Screenshot of my simultaneous upload issue:

[image]

### API Version

- 41

Should I do this check in ContentDocument trigger? However I don't want to even reach the backend. I wanted to deal with all these conditions in the frontend.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me .Have you filed a case with support ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of pain, I found a workaround.

Before this workaround, the lightning fileupload component creates an html like this:

```
<input type="file" id="input-1" aria-labelledby="input-1-form-label input-1-file-body-label" accept=".pdf, .jpg" multiple="" class="slds-file-selector__input slds-assistive-text">
```

After the workaround was implemented, the `multiple=""` disappeared.

The workaround is to explicitly set the `multiple` attribute to `false` in the controller.

The fileupload will look something like this (the important thing in this one is the aura:id, which will be used later):

```
<lightning:fileUpload 
    label="Attach receipt"
    multiple="false" 
    accept=".pdf, .jpg"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
    onuploadfinished="{! c.handleUploadFinished }" 
    aura:id="lightningFileUpload" />
```

In the component, I added a handler to the `render` event:

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
```

Once the render event finishes, I call the fileupload component, and set its multiple attribute to false:

```
onRender : function(component, event, helper) {
  component.find("lightningFileUpload").set("v.multiple", false);
}
```

It's the nearest workaround I can find that doesn't involve hacking my way via css, vanillaJS, or even catching stuff in the ContentDocument trigger.

Comment: Woooo .That never struck to me .Thats great working around the problem .+1 from me

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug to me for sure .The component outputs a HTML tag as below for the code

```
<lightning:fileUpload label="Attach receipt"
    name="fileUploader"
    accept=".pdf,.png"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
    onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
```

This is output as below . Notice multiple attribute in the input html tag .

```
<input type="file" id="input-1" aria-labelledby="input-1-form-label input-1-file-body-label" accept=".pdf,.png" multiple="" name="fileUploader" class="slds-file-selector__input slds-assistive-text">
```

There is not lot you could do than server validation as the hooks before file upload is not exposed to you as the developer .So report as a bug to SFDC .

Update

Sounds like SFDC has a fix .The below code is believed to work

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" > 
  <aura:attribute name="myRecordId" type="String" description="Record to which the files should be attached" /> 
  <aura:attribute name="multiple" type="Boolean" default="false" /> 
     <lightning:fileUpload label="Attach receipt." 
   multiple="{!v.multiple}" 
  accept=".pdf, .png" 
  recordId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
  onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" 
   aura:id="lightningfileUpload"/> 
</aura:component>
```

The controller code

```
({ 
    handleUploadFinished: function (cmp, event) { 
//  Get the list of uploaded files 
    var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files"); 
    alert("Files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length); 
   } 

})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I only have sandbox credentials. Is there any other way to raise this concern to salesforce without production creds?

Comment: No you need a PROD to do that .I can raise it on your behalf tomorrow and share details if you do not have access

Comment: I would appreciate it if you can report it on my behalf. Thank you very much.

Comment: Case opened for this one .The case no is 18239480

Comment: Hi Mohith. I found a workaround, I posted it below. Hopefully the lightning team can fix this for the next release.

Comment: Heard from support that this issue will be fixed and rolled out in all the orgs and sandboxes in coming days .